# php_printer.dll for php5.2.9

Tags: php, php-extension

I need to rum php_printer.dll for php version 5.2.9. Bt when I googled it, PECL file for correspondng version is not available. 
One option is to build it. 
Does anyone has a Compiled Version of php_printer.dll for php-5.2.9? 
Or please tell me on how to build a compiled version?

Thanks in advace,
Akhil

Answer (score 0):

Try the alternate mirror http://us.php.net/get/pecl-5.2.6-Win32.zip/from/a/mirror After find a link for same issue ( http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/173166-solved-php-printerdll/ )